# How does AppSync subscriptions handle resolver exceptions?

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, react-apollo, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I've noticed that throwing an exception in my subscription response mapping template results in the subscription not reaching the client.

I am building a chat feature and need to ensure new messages are delivered to client devices consistently. What happens if there is throttling exception (as a result of not provisioning enough RCU for example)? The client will be unaware that a new message unsuccessfully attempted to reach them.

Is there a way to retry the subscription, or at least inform the client so that they can pull new messages after a backoff period?

Comment: This question is not clear to me. If RCUs apply to DDB, why would an exception happen in AppSync response mapping template? If you are listening to DDB streams, then you won't get a notification if a write attempt was throttled. If this is about client initiating a subscription then Amplify returns an observable which has "error" callback: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/subscribe-data/q/platform/js/#using-aws-appsync-sdk